# Degree Dynamics Preferential Attachment Model

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to follow http://barabasi.com/f/622.pdf.

In page 11-12:

[image]

Solving this, I could not reach (5.7). After 5.6, I reach only up to:

[image]

Any hints on how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Ah... So just use ln properties... Ki goes from m to k, t goes from ti to t.